# Counting number of unique words in column

Tags: mysql

I have a table similar to this

```
quantity | part_numbers
1        | T101; T103
3        | T103; T102
1        | T101; T102; T103
```

I'm trying to work up a script that would return

```
part_number | quantity
T101        | 2
T102        | 4
T103        | 5
```

I've found this script that works but doesn't take into account quantities

```
SELECT SUM(total_count) as total, value
FROM (                   

SELECT (count(*)) AS total_count, REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(x.value,'?',''),'.',''),'!','') as value
FROM (                   
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(t.part_numbers, ' ', n.n), ' ', -1) value
  FROM order_items t CROSS JOIN 
(                        
   SELECT a.N + b.N * 10 + 1 n
     FROM                
    (SELECT 0 AS N UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL SELECT 4 UNION ALL SELECT 5 UNION ALL SELECT 6 UNION ALL SELECT 7 UNION ALL SELECT 8 UNION ALL SELECT 9) a
   ,(SELECT 0 AS N UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL SELECT 4 UNION ALL SELECT 5 UNION ALL SELECT 6 UNION ALL SELECT 7 UNION ALL SELECT 8 UNION ALL SELECT 9) b
    ORDER BY n           
) n                      
 WHERE n.n <= 1 + (LENGTH(t.part_numbers) - LENGTH(REPLACE(t.part_numbers, ' ', '')))
 ORDER BY value          

) AS x                   
GROUP BY x.value         

) AS y                   
GROUP BY value           
order by total desc
```

Comment: Just normalise.

Answer (score 2):

First, you should fix you data structure.  Storing lists as a delimited string is simply the wrong thing to do in SQL.  You should have a table with one row per item and per part.

Sometimes, we are stuck with other people's really bad design decisions.  You can modify the query you have to include quantity:

```
SELECT value, SUM(total_count), SUM(total_quantity)
FROM (SELECT COUNT(*) as total_count, SUM(quantity) as total_quantity   
             REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(x.value,'?',''),'.',''),'!','') as value
      FROM (SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(t.part_numbers, ' ', n.n), ' ', -1) as value, oi.quantity
            FROM order_items oi CROSS JOIN 
                 (SELECT d1.N + d2.N * 10 + 1 n
                  FROM (SELECT 0 AS N UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL SELECT 4 UNION ALL SELECT 5 UNION ALL SELECT 6 UNION ALL SELECT 7 UNION ALL SELECT 8 UNION ALL SELECT 9
                       ) d1 CROSS JOIN
                       (SELECT 0 AS N UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL SELECT 4 UNION ALL SELECT 5 UNION ALL SELECT 6 UNION ALL SELECT 7 UNION ALL SELECT 8 UNION ALL SELECT 9
                       ) d2
                 ) n                      
            WHERE n.n <= 1 + LENGTH(t.part_numbers) - LENGTH(REPLACE(t.part_numbers, ' ', ''))
           ) x                   
      GROUP BY x.value         
     ) y                   
GROUP BY value ;
```

The only real change I made to the query was to include the `quantity` in the various subqueries.

Other changes:

- Removed the comma in the `FROM` clause.  I abhor such commas.  Be explicit; use `CROSS JOIN`.
- Named the subqueries something more meaningful than `a` and `b`.  I use `d1` and `d2`, which in my mind is "digit 1" and "digit 2".
- Similarly use `oi` for `order_items` rathe than `t`.

Comment: Thanks, I'm not sure what most of this does (but it works) but I plan to replace the space separations with ; separations so I'll look through it and try to figure it out.